# String manipulation: How to add variable in / / pattern?

Tags: javascript, string-matching

```
var num = 1
var pattern = /hai/+num+/world/
```

It printed:

```
> "/hai/1/world/"
```

While I wanted it to print this:

```
> /hai1world/
```

any clue?

Comment: No clue. It is invalid JavaScript syntax.

Comment: @VisioN It's obviously valid JavaScript syntax since it computed a result value.

Comment: `new RegExp(/hai/.source+num+/world/.source)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var num = 1;
var pattern = new RegExp('hai' + num + 'world');
```

You can't use `/.../` with variables.